# How to control which rows were sent via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to create SSIS package which will periodically send data to other database. I want to send only new records(I need to keep sent records) so I created status column in my source table.

I want my package to update this column after successfuly sending data, but I can't update all rows wih "unsent" status because during package execution some rows may have been added, and I also can't use transactions(I mean on isolation levels that would solve my problem: I can't use Serializable beacause i musn't prevent users from adding new rows, and Sequence Container doesn't support Snapshot).

My next idea was to use recordset and after sending data to other db use it to get ids of sent rows, but I couldn't find a way to use it as datasource.

I don't think I should set status "to send" and then update it to "sent", I believe it would be to costly.

Now I'm thinking about using temporary table, but I'm not convinced that this is the right way to do it, am I missing something?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me.  What is it that you mean by "sending"?  Can you insert into the destination?  If so, what is preventing you from grabbing all the "unsent" records from the source and then using that datastream, in the same SSIS task, to check to see if the records already exist in the destination, and then, inserting them if they don't, and then marking them as sent back in the source, whether they were already there or not?

Comment: Is your problem one of sequencing?  In a task, you can use the same datastream to insert into the destination and update the source, but you cannot guarantee the sequence of those two, but you cannot easily pass data from one task to another to ensure sequencing?

Comment: I want to insert rows to table in destination db. I'm not sure how to use rows that i selected from source db multiple times, I can use it in DataFlow task, but i don't know how to access them in next SSIS block

Comment: @Anon316 I don't need sequencing as long as i'm sure that after executing package all data was changed or in case of error all data is rollbacked

Comment: What happens if you send a record but then it gets updated in the source, with different values?  You'd want to resend, right?

Comment: To user rows multiple times, use the multicast transform, but that only lets you use them in the same task.  If you want to use them in another task, you have to put the whole set into a variable (I tried using ADO set, but that was useless).  I ended up using a script (destination script) to stick them into a List<myObject>, and then putting that list into a variable.  Then when I needed to use the records in another task, i had a source script that put that List out as a datastream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record Set is a destination. You cannot use it in Data Flow task.
But since the data is saved to a variable, it is available in the Control flow.

After completing the DataFlow, come to the control flow and create a foreach component that can run on the ResultSet varialbe.
Read each Record Set value into a variable and use it to run an update query.

Also, see if "Lookup Transform" can be useful to you. You can generate rows that match or doesn't match.

I will improve the answer based on discussions

Comment: "I need to keep sent records", is this for the same purpose mentioned in the question? Or is it a requirement that serves something else. Hoping you know you can do what you asked in question, without saving the sent records.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear, i just don't want to lose data from source table. I mentioned because the number of rows in source table will grow in time and i will store a lot of rows there, and some solutions may be ineffective because of it.

Comment: You have two options. First is to run a foreach on the result set and run a separate insert for every row. You are using up a column called "status" here. I think the best way to do it is to use "Lookup". You can lookup using primary key, get the rows from source that are not already in destination, and just insert those

Comment: Here is a link on how to do it. It took me less than 30 minutes when I did the first time. Try it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a very typical data mirroring problem.  To start with, I would not simply have a boolean that signifies that a record was "sent" to the destination (mirror) database.  At the very least, I would put a LastUpdated datetime column in the source table, and have triggers on that table, on insert and update, that put the system date into that column.  Then, every day I would execute an SSIS package that reads the records updated in the last week, checks to see if those records exist in the destination, splitting the datastream into records already existing and records that do not exist in the destination.  For those that do exist, if the LastUpdated in the destination is less than the LastUpdated in the source, then update them with the values from the source.  For those that do not exist in the destination, insert the record from the source.

It gets a little more interesting if you also have to deal with record deletions.

I know it may seem wasteful to read and check a week's worth, every day, but your database should hardly feel it, it provides a lot of good double checking, and saves you a lot of headaches by providing a simple, error tolerant algorithm.  Some record does not get transferred because of some hiccup on the network, no worries, it gets picked up the next day.

I would still set up the SSIS package as a server task that sends me an email with any errors, so that I can keep track.  Most days, you get no errors, and when there are errors, you can wait a day or resolve the cause and let the next days run pick up the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar thing, in my case, I have a status on the source record.

1. I read in all records with a status of new.
2. Then use a **OLE DB Command** to execute SQL on each row, changing
   the status to "In progress"(in you where, enter a ? as the value in
   the Component Property tab, and you can configure it as a parameter
   from the table row like an ID or some pk in the Column Mappings
   tab).
3. Once the records are processed, you can change all "In Progress"
   records to "Success" or something similar using another OLE DB
   Command.

Depending on what you are doing, you can use the status to mark records that errored at some point, and require further attention.